# global indication of activity in android

Tags: android

in my app, i'm uploading some files that can take up to several minutes. i'm thinking of a way to notify the user about activity going on passively by adding a progress bar in my custom title bar. what i want to do is have every activity, each which uses the custom titles, appear with the progress bar until the thread finishes and does a callback which would make invisible the progress bar. can something like this be accomplished?

what seems to make this impossible is that if the user is in an activity with the view loaded, the thread finishing callback would have to manipulate the loaded view resources to disable the progess bar which doesn't seem feasible. are there any suggestions to accomplish this or alternative solutions in keeping a global and passive indication of something going in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to achieve this. [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

Basically how it would work, is you bind to the service in each activity when you create the activity. You use this service to start your upload method.

When you bind to the service you pass a handler, which is then used to update your UI in that specific activity. The service will never directly affect the UI (it will be running on a separate thread) instead the handler passes a message back to the UI thread with data in a Bundle, such as upload progress, or a bool to say it's finished.